# VLC - Adding to playlist

Tags: windows, mp3, vlc-media-player

I am using [Songr](http://songr.co.cc/) to find/stream songs and double click them to play in VLC which basically "plays" the URL. But as I am listening to one item and search for another and double click another item from the results, it replaces the currently playing item in VLC.

How do I set it up such that double clicking adds to the current playlist? When I see now is that it adds the new item to the end of the playlist and proceeds to play it.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

create batch file as below

> `@echo off
>
>   "c:\program files (x86)\videolan\vlc\vlc.exe" --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue %1`

(the second line should not be broken, and replace the vlc path with your computer path

then link the default file type to this batch file (i.e. open the file with this batch file)

i just tested this and it works properly with my computer =)